# Bitmap ColorMatrix change saturation for one color only

Tags: android, bitmap, colormatrix

Is there a way to change ColorMatrix of a Bitmap in a way so I can "turn off" only one color, just like in photoshop.

Original image:

[image]

Filtered image without blue color (saturation for blue moved from 0 to -100):

[image]

***----EDIT----***

I am trying to achieve PhotoShop effect with this tool:

[image]

Comment: see android.graphics.AvoidXfermode

Comment: How should I use it? I don't think it can do what I asked for. Or I don't know how to set it...

Comment: I couldn't make desired effect with AvoidXfermode.

Comment: actually your problem is not what you expect, you are saying: `Filtered image without blue color` but on your image there is much area with blue color: there is `cyan` on the left and `purple` on the right that have much `blue` ingridients

Comment: Yeah, I know there is some blue color left. Check out edit in question.